# How to properly update the local variables with rpmbuild spec file?

Tags: rpm, yum, updating, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I need to periodically update multiple CentOS servers with a custom software package using RPM packaging. The software has multiple directories and files, some of which are configuration files which has multiple variables with local server-specific values.

I've been reading the RPM documentation about [configuration files](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s03.html) which is explaining how to make them properly and so to leave them untouched. But I actually need to update the content of configuration files too preserving only some local variable values. So I see two possible ways:

1. Mark such files as configuration files and using the `%post` directive in rpmuild's spec file to update each such file with the difference after `yum update` is executed remote server.
2. The second way is just the opposite: `yum update` replaces everything, but thanks to `%post` directive some variables on the respective files on remote servers are updated with the local values.

So my question is which way is better one, which way is recommended by experienced RPM package builders - I am total newbie here, so bear with me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to local configuration with *.rpm packaging is to change the configuration paradigm to include 2 files, one containing generic default configuration from the package, the other having local configuration with (possible) overrides.

RPM does best distributing static content, not mutable configuration files.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your input. Could you please also explain how then two files interact with each other? I mean the custom program need to have configuration file with number of variables that need to take local values. Let' assume I pushed two such files in the suggested way, but then again the remote system needs to use just one configuration file, so it should be somehow updated with local values anyway.

Comment: Set reasonable defaults in the generic configuration distributed in the package and then provide local overrides generated as needed, using %post if necessary. RPM is great for static unchanging content, but not so good for local configuration. Splitting into 2 parts makes local configuration easier.

Comment: I am suggesting you modify the application, not just the packaging, to handle local configuration/overrides in a separate file.

Comment: Sorry for I am confused - how should I modify the application on multiple servers just after automatic updates on such servers pull new RPM package? I thought I had to use `%post` directive to do so, and if I do then is there real need to have two files per each configuration file?

Comment: Explain your need to the application developers. Otherwise, depending on the type of configuration, split into generic and local configuration and concatenate into a final configuration in %post. You can also repeat the customization using %verifyscript as well as %post. Meanwhile rpm has nothing other than %post to handle customization: my suggestion to separate is merely a way to do KISS by refactoring and concatenating rather than editing a file distributed with rpm.

Comment: Well, I am the application developer and I am trying to sync it to multiple servers using rpm for the first time. And that is why I am confused how my application takes local values after has been installed or updated on each remote server. I am interested in `refactoring and concatenating` part, can you elaborate hod do I do that so each server put's its own values into resulting configuration files?

Comment: modified %config files are always renamed by rpm and so require fixing after install. Unmodified %config files will be upgraded without renaming even if there are changes between old and new versions. Splitting local into a separate file permits the generic config to be upgraded by rpm without renaming. Local configuration has to be generated in %post: if all info is generated, you can avoid find/replace etc, just clobber the local config while generating. The application either needs to read config from 2 files, or you will have to merge/concatenate the generic and local config in %post.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I couldn't figure out how to merge/concatenate, so will just search and replace for now. Still I accept your answer as you seem to be providing the right way to do things, it's just me, an RPM newbie, who can't figure out.